# What is wrong with my Browserify JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, browserify

In my `main.js`, I have:

```
var example = require('./test');
example.speak('Hello world');
```

While in my `test.js`, I have:

```
module.exports = function() {
    this.speak = function(str) {
        str += ' < you typed.';
        return str;
    };
    this.listen = function(str) {
        return str;
    };
};
```

What exactly am I doing wrong so that I can use `browserify` correctly with this?

Comment: An exported constructor function won't automatically be invoked by `require()` or browserify. The module that's using it must do that itself, `var Test = require('./test'), example = new Test();`.

Comment: `var example = new require ...`

Comment: You are exporting a function/constructor not an object. You can use `new` for creating a new instance and then call `speak`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either export an object:

```
module.exports = {
    speak: function () {},
    // etc
}
```

or use

```
var example = new require("./test")();
```